# Is this good style?

Tags: c++, coding-style, parameter-passing

I have some parameters in my functions that receive and pass around the same value.  Should I name all the parameter variables the same?

Example:

```
// assume numMonth = 12
// assume numYear = 2000

int promptMonth(); // returns numMonth
int promptYear();  // returns numYear

int daysInMonth(int numMonth, int numYear); // numMonth and numYear will always
int daysInYear(int numYear);                // be sent to these.

bool isLeapYear(int numYear);               // daysInYear() and daysInMonth() call
                                            // this function and send it numYear 
                                            // (which would be 2000 in this case).
```

Should all those parameters be named the same since the same value is passed to each of them?

Comment: What do you mean by "same value"?

Comment: I meant if `numMonth` is assigned 12 in `promptMonth()` the parameter variable `numMonth` in the function `daysInMonth()` is also 12 because `numMonth` from `promptMonth()` is passed to `daysInMonth()`. So the variable `numMonth` is and _should_ always be the same value, which was 12 in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By same, I assume you mean the function parameter name `numYear`.

Yes it is always good practice to name the variables in a meaningful way which indicates the meaning/purpose of the value being passed.

And those variables are part of different functions, hence there scope is limited to those functions only, So there is no problem of multiple definitions if you are thinking of that.

Answer (score 4):

Generally this style is a good idea. You should definitely follow it, but there is still space for misuse and misinterpretation.

Let me explain myself

- **Misinterpretation:** even if you *do* name the variables consistently, the reader might not convinced that you mean it.
- **Misuse:**  perhaps *not any* `int` is suitable as a year value.

For more complex cases you should consider using a special type for your input variables.
For example, consider changing some of your *integers* into:

```
Month promptMonth();
Year promptYear();

int daysInMonth( Month m, Year y); 
int daysInYear( Year y );

bool isLeapYear( Year );
```

Can you see that now not only you don't have to use complex variable names, but you are also able to do special prints and checks?

```
cout << "the current month is " << promptMonth();
```

could output

```
the current month is 'October'
```